# Looking for documentation on ‘path’ argument in TabularDataBunch.from_df()

Tags: python-3.x, categorical-data, embedding, fast-ai

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of `path` (mandatory) argument in `TabularDataBunch.from_df(path=path,df=df,...)` of fast.ai library in Python 3.6.

I checked [documentation](https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.data.html#TabularDataBunch.from_df), but can't seem to find the details there.
In particular, I have a `pd.DataFrame` that does not have an associated CSV file on a disk. How do I go about applying `.from_df` method to it?

Does anyone have more info or links to references?

Answer (score 1):

Found an [example here that helped](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/1417) with path value as `'output'`. Also, [the fast.ai lecture 4 video (43rd minute)](https://youtu.be/gbceqO8PpBg?t=2580) defines `path` as the output location for the output results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aabbccabca'), 'B': np.random.normal(size=10).round(2), 'Y': list('aabbccabca')})
tfms = [Categorify]
tblrData = TabularDataBunch.from_df('output', df, dep_var='Y', valid_idx=[7,8], procs=tfms, cat_names=['A'], bs=4)
(cat_x,cont_x),y = next(iter(tblrData.train_dl))
for o in (cat_x, cont_x, y): print(to_np(o[:5]))
```

`bs` is a batch size parameter here.